How to install and compile the matconvnet in Mac silicon version
I’m having trouble installing MatConvNet on my Mac with an M3 Pro chip. When I try to compile it using the command vl_compilenn('verbose', 2), I get the error “Unsupported architecture ‘maca64’.” I’ve attempted several methods to resolve this issue, including running make, but nothing seems to work.
I’m eager to find a solution for this problem in the M1/M3 environment, as I’ve noticed that there are very few resources addressing this specific issue.

The repository on GitHub for this project hasn’t been updated in 6 years, Apple Silicon (M-series CPUs) didn’t exist yet. So it’s not surprising it doesn’t work. There’s an issue from last year about this here: https://github.com/vlfeat/matconvnet/issues/1265
